# Show YouTube Videos URLs and thumbnails in listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to show multiple YouTube videos URLs (that are in arraylist) in the listview. This listview should show both URL and thumbnail of that video and if the user select any video, it should play in next full screen.

How can I do that in both Java and XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the URLs & Video data is provided by a Backend of yours, the steps would be as follows:

**1) Create a Java class named 'Video'**

```
public class Video
{
    String Thumbnail;
    String Url;
    String Title;

    //GET & SET Methods
}
```

For more information about Java Classes, [refer this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html).

Add all your video objects to an ArrayList of type Video

Example: `ArrayList<Video> videos = new ArrayList<~>();`

**2) Create a new android layout named 'single_video_item.xml' in the R.layout directory**

In order to display a list of videos in your ListView, we first need to define how a single row looks like. The file would be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Video Title"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**3) Create a custom ListView adapter of type Video**

In order to display all the videos, you need a custom ListView adapter that iterates through your ArrayList objects. [Refer this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) for more information about ListView adapters.

Name the file as 'FeedAdapter.java' & use the following code

```
public class FeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Video> {
    public FeedAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Video> videos) {
       super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Get the data item for this position
       Video currentVideo = getItem(position);    
       // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
       if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_video_item, parent, false);
       }
       // Lookup view for data population
       TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
       ImageView thumbnail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
       // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
       title.setText(currentVideo.Title);
       //And similarly set your imageview data, etc

       // Return the completed view to render on screen
       return convertView;
   }
}
```

Read a bit about [Custom adapters](https://www.sitepoint.com/custom-data-layouts-with-your-own-android-arrayadapter/) to gain a bit more exposure on the subject.

Now that we've arranged the basic setup of the Adapters, let's set the Custom adapter we've created to the ListView & pass the list of videos.

In your Activity's onCreate, define the ListView & initialize the FeedAdapter:

```
//This is the listview in your main activity's xml
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.feedListView);
FeedAdapter<Video> adapter = new FeedAdapter(this, videos);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This would be the main structure of your code. Please read more about Custom ListView adapters to get a clearer idea about the procedure. Goodluck!

P.S: I wrote the entire code by memory, let me know if there are any syntax errors! ;)

**EDIT**

If you receive the Thumbnail as an image Url, checkout [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) by Facebook. It allows you to pass an Image URL & set that as an Image in your ListView. If you choose this method, you won't be needing the android ImageView.